# Oracle : Table or view doesn't exist

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to create a view in Oracle using Toad and getting error table or view doesn't exist.

But when I run the query on its own it executes successfully. What is the possible reason ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW MGR.V_INDEX_PERFORMANCE
(
          INDEX_ID ,
          INDEX_NAME,
          MTD,
          YTD 
)
   BEQUEATH DEFINER
AS

SELECT    "INDEX_ID" ,
          "INDEX_NAME",
          "MTD",
          "YTD" from MIS_PERMAL.MV_INDEX_PERFORMANCE 
   where INDEX_ID in (1045, 2005) AND FIELD_CODE = 'TR' AND CCY_CODE IN ('D', 'USD') order by INDEX_ID, price_date desc;
```

Comment: Are you running the query on its own as `MGR` user? The view owner has to be granted select on the tables in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's permissions, or rather the way they are granted. The MGR user has a privilege to query the underlying table which comes from a role. Oracle does not allow us to build views or procedures using privileges from a role. This is just the way the security model works.

The solution is to ask the table owner MIS_PERMAL (or a power user such as a DBA) to grant the SELECT privilege on MV_INDEX_PERFORMAMCE directly to MGR.